# Docker compose volume mount ignores the data

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker compose file as:

```
    ...
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
    volumes:
      - ./tablestruct:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/folder1
      - ./tablestruct1:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/folder2

volumes:
  folder1:
  folder2:
```

When i run compose up, i get:

**postgres_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/folder1
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/folder2**

Answer (score 2):

From dockerhub postgres image documentation:

> If you would like to do additional initialization in an image derived
>   from this one, add one or more *.sql, *.sql.gz, or *.sh scripts under
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d (creating the directory if necessary).
>   After the entrypoint calls initdb to create the default postgres user
>   and database, it will run any *.sql files, run any executable *.sh
>   scripts, and source any non-executable *.sh scripts found in that
>   directory to do further initialization before starting the service.
>
> Warning: scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d are only run if you
>   start the container with a data directory that is empty; any
>   pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup. One
>   common problem is that if one of your /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
>   scripts fails (which will cause the entrypoint script to exit) and
>   your orchestrator restarts the container with the already initialized
>   data directory, it will not continue on with your scripts.

You should move everything to the same directory and mount it as `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` and not a folder inside it.

So:

```
volumes:
  - ./tablestruct:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```